# What should I use for local version control?

Tags: version-control, controls, version, local

Is there a version control out there that is free that doesn't store my files on a server, but rather on my local hard drive?

Other information

- I am currently building small websites on ASP.NET in Visual Studio

Comment: Git, subversion, and many others will do this.  But I have to ask why -- using github or visual studio online will ensure your code is safe if something bad happens to your local computer.

Comment: thats true i never thought of that, i just wanted something simple.

Comment: Related Software Engineering: [Version control for independent developers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/27147/168744)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Git for local version control. https://git-scm.com/

Comment: Can you brief a little bit more on how can we use it for local versioning control?

Comment: don't push the commits to repository.

Comment: As a supplement, this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3Qhon09JEw) illustrates this answer in action. Thanks, all, for the info!